# What is the best way to do this SQL task?

Tags: sql

What would be the best approach with this SQL-based logic:

I need to get some groups from a table. However there are thousands of items, which can belong to only one of those groups (say one of the five/ten/fifteen groups returned). I can get the groups and then loop all of the item objects and insert them into the group.

Or would it be better to get all the objects which belong to a group, loop them, and insert them into the belonging group?  What would be the difference in performance?

Comment: I would seriously question if you're doing any 'looping'

Comment: Why would you in any case ever loop for an insert/update/delete? You need to think in terms of sets, looping is a very bad thing to do to an innocent database.

Comment: Example data and expected output would really help clarify what you have, and what you want to end up with.  Database this is to be performed on can affect things too.  SQL is SET based, not procedural so the concept of looping is last-ditch to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for the groups, then a simple `SELECT DISTINCT group FROM Table` will return those.   If you want each of the rows and their associated groups, well a `SELECT *` (not for production use...) would get that as well.  If you want them in order, then a `SELECT` with an `ORDER BY group` would do.

What are you going to do with this information?